# Problema con funciones en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla Oferta con estas columnas:

```
Schema::create('ofertas', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('titulo');
        $table->text('descripcion');
        $table->string('empresa');
        $table->string('sector');
        $table->date('fecha_limite');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Ademas, tiene esta función en Oferta.php:

```
public function caducado(){
    return strtotime($this->fecha_limite)<strtotime(date("d-m-Y")); // Si devuelve verdadero, es que la oferta ha caducado al pasar la fecha limite.
}
```

Esta comprueba si la fecha limite de la oferta ha pasado, o aun no.
Quiero usarlo para filtrar una lista de ofertas en OfertaController.php:

```
public function filtrar(){
    $ofertas=Oferta::all()->where('caducado',false);
    return view('listas.ofertas',compact('ofertas'));
}
```

Pero me sale esto: `Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\caducado()`

¿Como lo soliciono?

Edito: Se que para convocar el metodo de una tabla no puedo hacer $oferta->caducado, sino `$oferta->caducado()`. La pregunta es cual seria el homologo en el `where()`.

PD: Viendo que no es posible utilizar la función, he utilizado este código:

```
public function filtrar(){
    $ofertas=Oferta::all()->where(strtotime('fecha_limite'),'<',strtotime(date("d-m-Y")));
    return view('listas.ofertas',compact('ofertas'));
}
```

El problema que ahora me encuentro es que tengo 2 ofertas: Una con fecha de `2018-05-01` (esta caducada) y otra de `2018-05-15` (no ha caducado aun). Se supone que se mostrar la 2ª oferta, pero no la 1ª, al estar ya caducada, pero adivinen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: desde donde llamas a la funcion `caducado` ?

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez Esta en la operación $ofertas=Oferta::all()->where('caducado',false);

Comment: En el where, concretamente.

Comment: Creo que en el where solo puedes pasar campos de la tabla, no funciones

Comment: a eso me refería yo , que de donde saca caducado, solo se puede llamar campos de tabla en ese where , colo lo dice @alanfcm

Comment: @SebastiánLagosYañez He editado mi pregunta para añadir más información.

Comment: El problema es que haces Oferta::all() que las devuelve todas, y luego el where lo haces en una Collection, no en el where.
Yo probaria esto: `Oferta::where(strtotime('fecha_limite'),'<',strtotime(date("d-m-Y")))->get();`

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado un modo para que funcione:

```
public function filtrar(){
   $ofertas=Oferta::all()->where('fecha_limite','>',now()->toDateString());
    return view('listas.ofertas',compact('ofertas'));
}
```

Si la fecha límite es superior a la fecha acual, la oferta no habra caducado aun. Si la fecha límite es igual o inferior a la fecha actual, la oferta límite habra caducado.